# modifying dataframes in a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary of Dataframes just like this:

```
variables = [x, y, z, t]
dictionary_of_dataframes = {'df1':pd.DataFrame(data1, columns =variables),'df2' : pd.DataFrame(data2, columns =variables),'df3' : pd.DataFrame(data3, columns =variables)}
```

i'm trying to convert some of the data that are stored in variables into numeric.

```
for elem in dictionary_of_logs:
    elem[['x','y']].apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

but it returns me `TypeError: string indices must be integers`. 
Is it possible to so in a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use for in dict, you will get only keys.
If you want iterate values, use:

```
for elem in dictionary_of_logs.values():
    elem[['x','y']].apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

Comment: perfect! but it also doesn't change the previous dataframe... how do I asign the dictionary name to it if i'm iterating over dictionary_of_logs.values()?